# sql select from table name described in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select from a sql table which has its table name described in another table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM first_table t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t1.other_table t2 WHERE t1.other_table_id = t2.id)
```

Can't find a solution to this!

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL and put the table name in a variable to build out a string for your select.

Comment: Why do you have a table name in a column? That doesn't seem to make much sense (unless you are writing a DBMS). Maybe you'd want some advice on your database design.

Comment: @mrlindell Did any of the answers work for you? Please select an answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You could use dynamic variables with queries:

```
SET @table := (select tableName from test limit 1);
set @qry1:= concat('select * from ',@table);
prepare stmt from @qry1 ;
execute stmt ;
```

**OR** even:

```
set @qry1:= concat('select * from ', (select tableName from test limit 1));
select @qry1;
prepare stmt from @qry1 ;
execute stmt ;
```

**SQLFiddle Example:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a787e3/1

Note: SqlFiddle doesn't allow running `execute` in the right-editor, so I had to use a view.

### Disclaimers/Notes:

You should sanitize all inputs to the tableName table. This is so that no one will insert SQL into this table and execute it.

Additionally, please note that in a real database we would have a `where` condition on the table selection query.

Example:

```
set @qry1:= concat('select * from ', (select tableName from test where id='something'));
```

Comment: This looks prone and suspect to second order (stored) SQL injection vectors.

Comment: Besides SQL is **unsorted** dataset using `limit` without `order by` is **meaningless** in MySQL. Because MySQL without using `order by` is free to return anny record from table as "first" record.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland  Seriously? It's just sample... you want a disclaimer about it's somewhat fictional nature? I could just as easily have used `where id = '' ` or whatever.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland  If you have a better solution, you are welcome to contribute a sanitized version.

Comment: "you want a disclaimer about it's somewhat fictional nature?" fictional nature? it is pretty known fact that `limit` or `top` (for that matter) is meaningless without `order by` to bad most of the times not mentioned in most DMBS documentions, PostgreSQL docs are mentioning this.. "I could just as easily have used where id = '' or whatever." Also `limit` and using `where` without `order by` to select the "first" record is more or less  the same case because the where statement can match multiple records unless offcource you are using a primary or unique key

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT * 
   FROM first_table t1 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM other_table t2 WHERE t1.other_table_id = t2.id)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql> SELECT @other_table := other_table FROM first_table WHERE 1 = 1;
mysql> SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", @other_table);
mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
mysql> DEALLOCATE stmt;
```

Here `WHERE 1=1` should be changed to return only one row in the result-set

Comment: This looks prone and suspect to second order (stored) SQL injection vectors.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for providing this answer.
    `mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @s;` declares `stmt` but later on you are using `stmt1`. Should `stmt1` be renamed to `stmt`?

Comment: @Florian, Yes you are correct. I will update the answer